# Unity 3D fade from one skybox to another

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, skybox

I have four different skyboxes, one for each season in my game.

How can I create a fade transition between the skyboxes in c#?

So for example, at a certain point, the summer skybox fades into the autumn skybox.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to do the blending in a shader, there's [one on the Unify wiki](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=SkyboxBlended) that can blend between two skyboxes.

You need to swap the textures in your material using a script (using material.SetTexture) when it's finished blending between 2 of them to get the effect of blending between 4.

Comment: I've set up the shader and material and the skybox blends using the slider. How can i write it in my code (c#) so that it gradually animates from blend = 0.0 to blend = 1? I understand you can use    
  skyboxmaterial.SetFloat("_Blend", blendNumber ); 

But I need the blend Number to be gradually incremented over a set time.

Comment: You can use Mathf.Lerp(start, end, time) to get a value between two others, where time is between 0 and 1. The easy (but technically wrong) way to use it is something like this:

`material.SetFloat("_Blend" , Mathf.Lerp(material.GetFloat("_Blend"),1,Time.deltaTime));`

but that gives you fast blending at the start, and slows down to a stop just before reaching 1. The best way to do it is laid out well in this article:https://chicounity3d.wordpress.com/2014/05/23/how-to-lerp-like-a-pro/

Comment: Then again, if the _Blend parameter's range is 0 to 1, you probably don't need Lerp anyway, you can just increment a timer variable yourself using Time.deltaTime and use that.

Comment: How do I add the Sky boxes to the blending shader, they are materials and i'm not quite sure how to go about this.